# How do i filter using a partial VM name (string) in vmware vSphere client REST API?

Tags: vsphere, vmware-tools

Good day!

i am trying to automate some actions to be done to VM's in my organisation.
The action to be done depends on the a substring in the VM name.

for eg, i would need to delete all VM's whose name starts with 'delete', etc.

I can use the below API to fetch the list of VM's:

**GET** https://{{vc}}/rest/vcenter/vm

However, this API can only fetch a maximum of 1000 VM's.

Is there any way i can filter and get only the list of VM's with the expected substring from this API?

from what i understand, appending filter.names.1 to the above API works but for that i need to input the exact and entire VM name.

is there a way where i can search for a list of VM's with partial text?

Apologies, i am a newbie to this.

thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the vSphere Automation API isn't setup to filter on partial names or even when using a wildcard. Some of the available filters may help you limit the output to be under the 1000 object limit (example: filter on specific clusters and/or folders).

Hopefully this is something that's added in a future release.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Kyle. For the moment, as suggested by you, i have used another filter to limit the results to within 1000 results, and since i am using postman to trigger the API, i will be writing javascript code to filter out and get the list of VM's i need based on substring.

Answer (score 2):

```
Since vSphere API does not provide such capability to search by partial VM name there is a tricky way to do this.
I am using the search functionality in vSphere Client 6.7.0.
Prerequisite is to get the following cookies first:

    VSPHERE-USERNAME
    VSPHERE-CLIENT-SESSION-INDEX
    VSPHERE-UI-JSESSIONID

You have to do three calls in order to get them:

1. GET "https://[URL]/ui/login" you will be forwarded to a new URL from where you can take "SAMLRequest token"
2. POST "https://[URL]/websso/SAML2/SSO/vsphere.local?SAMLRequest=[SAMLRequest token]", set as header "CastleAuthorization=Basic%20[credentials]" where credentials is the Base64 encoding of "User:Password". Get the value of "SAMLResponse" hidden field from the response.
3. POST "https://[URL]/ui/saml/websso/sso", set "SAMLResponse=[SAMLResponse value]", where "SAMLResponse value" you have it from the previous response. From this response you will get the cookies.

Once you have those three cookies, make a new call as you set the cookies
4. GET "https://[URL]/ui/search/quicksearch/?opId=0&query=[partial VM name]"

For example for this call "https://[URL]/ui/search/quicksearch/?opId=0&query=test"
you will get response like this:
[{
        "icon": "vsphere-icon-vm",
        "labelPlural": "Virtual Machines",
        "label": "Virtual Machine",
        "results": [{
                "id": "urn:vmomi:VirtualMachine:vm-2153:103ac083-e314-47ea-942a-c685d9a4e6c9",
                "type": "VirtualMachine",
                "name": "TestVM1"
            }, {
                "id": "urn:vmomi:VirtualMachine:vm-3391:103ac083-e314-47ea-942a-c685d9a4e6c9",
                "type": "VirtualMachine",
                "name": "TestVM2"
            }, {
                "id": "urn:vmomi:VirtualMachine:vm-3438:103ac083-e314-47ea-942a-c685d9a4e6c9",
                "type": "VirtualMachine",
                "name": "TestVM3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Below is my own vSphere Search Proxy Client written in C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

namespace VsphereSearchProxy
{
    static class Program
    {
        const string VSPHERE_URL = "VSPHERE_URL";

        static string VSPHERE_CRED_BASE64
        {
            get
            {
                var plainTextCred = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("USER:PASS");
                return Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextCred);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Expected one argument: Virtual Machine name");
                return;
            }

            var vmName = args[0];
            var vsphereUri = VSPHERE_URL.TrimEnd('/');

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

            //=================================================================

            Console.WriteLine("\nStep 1\n");

            var url1 = vsphereUri + "/ui/login";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url1);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var url2 = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
            Console.WriteLine("url2: " + url2);

            WebHeaderCollection headerCollection = response.Headers;
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse headers\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < headerCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + headerCollection.GetKey(i) + " = " + headerCollection.Get(i));
            }

            //=================================================================

            Console.WriteLine("\nStep 2\n");

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url2);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic " + VSPHERE_CRED_BASE64);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write("CastleAuthorization=Basic%20" + VSPHERE_CRED_BASE64);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("Expected 200 OK, but got " + response.StatusCode);
            }

            headerCollection = response.Headers;
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse headers\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < headerCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + headerCollection.GetKey(i) + " = " + headerCollection.Get(i));
            }

            var responseString = "";

            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var SAMLResponse = "";
            Match match = Regex.Match(responseString, "<input[^>]*type=\"hidden\"\\s+name=\"SAMLResponse\"[^>]*value=\"([^\"]*)\"");

            if (match.Success)
            {
                SAMLResponse = match.Groups[1].Value;
                SAMLResponse = SAMLResponse.Replace("\n", "");
                //Console.WriteLine("SAMLResponse: " + SAMLResponse);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SAMLResponse))
            {
                throw new Exception("SAMLResponse is missing or blank");
            }

            //=================================================================

            Console.WriteLine("\nStep 3\n");

            var url3 = vsphereUri + "/ui/saml/websso/sso";

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url3);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic " + VSPHERE_CRED_BASE64);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write("SAMLResponse=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SAMLResponse));
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var cookies = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
            Console.WriteLine("cookies: " + cookies);

            headerCollection = response.Headers;
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse headers\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < headerCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + headerCollection.GetKey(i) + " = " + headerCollection.Get(i));
            }

            //=================================================================

            Console.WriteLine("\nStep 4\n");

            var url4 = vsphereUri + "/ui/search/quicksearch/?opId=:1&query=" + vmName;

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url4);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("Cookie: " + cookies);
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("Expected 200 OK, but got " + response.StatusCode);
            }

            var jsonResp = "";

            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                jsonResp = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(jsonResp);
        }
    }
}
```